# Swagger description of a REST service

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have the following REST-call:

```
public MyRpObject getSubadminVerfueger(
        @QueryParam("klientNr") final String klientNr,
        @QueryParam("klientId") final String klientId,
        @Context final ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    ....
}
```

And I am trying to make a description via Swagger:

```
@Operation(summary = "Summary",
        description = "Description",
        requestBody = @RequestBody(
                content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json")))
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "200",
        content = @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(description = "Response description",
                implementation = MyRpObject.class)))
```

I am wondering how should I mark the Query params in the request body in the operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [@Parameters](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.1.10/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/Parameters.html) and [@Parameter](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v2.1.10/apidocs/io/swagger/v3/oas/annotations/Parameter.html), for example:

```java
@Parameters({
    @Parameter(name = "klientNr", in = ParameterIn.QUERY, schema = @Schema(type = "string")),
    @Parameter(name = "klientId", in = ParameterIn.QUERY, schema = @Schema(type = "string"))
})
```